# please, help to identify bush

Tags: identification, shrubs

[image][image]

Please, help do identify this bush, it is from previous owner and is overgrown. I would like to trim it, but need to know the right technic, e.g. I believe I need to make it 2 feet smaller, but if I do it all the leaves will be gone, so probably have to do it in early winter, but not sure how much I can trim

Comment: What part of the world are you in please?